# Pandas shows data only with Python Shell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm using Pandas for the first time and I saw that if I run a saved script in the shell it doesn't work, but if I run it writing line by line in the shell it shows me a table. Why?

The script is this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:\data.csv')
df
```

Thank you!

Comment: Because the interactive interpreter shows the result of each expression by default. If that’s what you want, `print(df)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, I didn't read the question properly. I'm surprised the file path was not (part of) the problem here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you! Now it's working!